# Unity scene became darker

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a project, and its looks like this:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1013067128234057829/1026447806635986984/unknown.png?width=1111&height=625

i changed my system from windows 10 to windows 11, and restored my project from cloud, and now its looks like so:
[image]

i didnt change any settings at all, what happened? how i can get back my old illumination?
btw editor in scene and game window now showing only with 3-6 fps, and its really weird. pls help

Comment: is your monitor HDR? Windows 11 changes how content looks on HDR.

Comment: on the other hand it looks to me like it's a different time of day. Are you sure it's the exact same scene with the exact same settings?